# Is Rheumatic fever more Chronic than acute?

Tags: microbiology, inflammation

It follows from the complication of S.pyogenes' pharyngitis.
I am thinking how the inflammatory response behaves: acute or chronic or something between.

I think chronic disease is better description here than acute, however not sure.

**What is the type of inflammatory response in the Rheumatic fever?**

Answer (score 1):

the inflammatory response it autoimmune reaction, thus it occurs 4 weeks after the Strep infection.

please, look at the picture from the "[Nature](http://www.nature.com/nrcardio/journal/v10/n3/fig_tab/nrcardio.2012.197_F4.html)" -

[image]

Comment: So it is chronic, since not rapid.